# My Qt app cannot read accents from MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

i have a problem when trying to get Data from my DB in MySQL.

I have a table in that DB and i have several columns there. From column ´Profesor´ i want to get some teachers names but **Spanish Names** use **accents** or **Ñ** that can't be read by the below algorithm. For example, in my column 'Profesor' there is one 'FÉRNANDO' that query.value() (variable **"a"**) in Qt interprets 'FÃ‰RNANDO'. The algorithm is this:

```
QSqlQuery query(QSqlDatabase::database("Conexion1"));
query.prepare("SELECT * FROM año2017");
query.exec();
p = 0;
while(query.next()){
        a = query.value(query.record().indexOf("Profesor")).toString();
        d = query.value(query.record().indexOf("Grupo")).toString();
        for(int j = 0; j < 1; j++){
            if(p == 0){
                p++;
                j--;
                consulta = "--Busqueda--";
            }else{
                consulta = a+" "+"("+d+")";
            }
            ui->comboBox->addItem(consulta);
            ui->comboBox_2->addItem(consulta);
            ui->comboBox_3->addItem(consulta);
            ui->comboBox_4->addItem(consulta);
            ui->comboBox_5->addItem(consulta);            
        }
}
```

Comment: What encoding is the text in your database?

Comment: Unicode and UTF-8 encoding are good things. You should make sure that both your database and program use them - and if not (for some bizare reason) you should at least make sure that you agree on what alternate character set and encoding you use - but *really*; just use unicode encoded as UTF-8 everywhere.

Comment: @RichardCritten The encoding in my DB is UTF-8.

Comment: @JesperJuhl  I think i'm not authorized to change MySQL encoding. i'm working with that DB but its not mine. It would be better if i could change the encoding of my Qt program but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: Try `a = QString::fromUtf8(query.value(query.record().indexOf("Profesor")).toByteArray())`, or the overloaded version `a = QString::fromUtf8(query.value("Profesor").toByteArray())`

Comment: @putu The problem persist

Comment: @JesperJuhl This is a Qt application, so strings are going to be in UTF-16, not UTF-8.

Comment: Then you need to add the following query: `query.execute("SET NAMES utf8")` before your `SELECT` query.

Comment: I've finally found the solution: the only one thing you must do is add after  **a = query.value(query.record().indexOf("Profesor")).toString();** the following line: **a = a.toLocal8Bit();**

Comment: @putu But MySQL table is already encoded in UTF-8, the problem of my Qt app is that it couldn't read UTF-8 encoded characters

Comment: The query is not for setting the database encoding (the user may don't have any right to change the database/table encoding). It only affects user  connection session

Comment: I have another problem when i pass a QString that contains accents to MySQL db, it is unable to read the accents

Comment: @putu If i set this `query.execute("SET NAMES utf8")` my problem continues with the illegible characters